# Which projective varieties are étale over affine space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Liu's answer to this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16331/when-does-a-projective-morphism-give-an-etale-morphism-into-affine-space-fin) there is a characterization of smooth *affine* varieties which are étale over affine space. I was wondering if one can give a similar characterization for projective varieties.

Let $X$ be a smooth *projective* variety of dimension $n$. When is $X$ étale over $\mathbb A^n$? How can one construct an étale map $X\to \mathbb A^n$?

I should maybe point out that I'm primarily interested in the case when the base field is $\mathbb C$.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Alternatively, you could ask which projective varieties are etale over projective space. The answer would be equally disappointing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you explain it a little bit more? Now proper subvarieties of projective space are not just points. So what is the contradiction?

Comment: Dear Brenin, there is no basic contradiction (that I know of), but nevertheless it is true that projective space has no etale covers by a projective variety. For $\mathbf P^1$ this is an easy application of Riemann--Hurwitz. One can then extend this to higher dimensions by an inductive argument. See this MO question and (great) answers for details: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62282/mathbbpn-is-simply-connected

Comment: Thanks! Those answers are really instructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image of a projective variety under any morphism is proper, and the only subvarieties of $\mathbb{A}^n$ that are proper are those of dimension $0$.  So a projective variety of dimension $n$ is etale over $\mathbb{A}^n$ iff $n=0$.